# digitalocean batch processing

Tags: docker, batch-processing, digital-ocean

Wondering if digitalocean has a solution/alternative like aws has for batch job processing?

Something that automatically spins up X droplets(instances) does the job and then shuts down?

Trying to figure out how this can be implemented (maybe with not that much manually work)

Comment: What do you want processed? Reach out using the link in my profile and i can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution/product for this